# ioctl: invalid argument for HDIO_GET_IDENTITY

Tags: centos, hard-disk, c

I wrote a program to get the details of hard disk drive using `HDIO_ ioctl calls`.

For writing program, I'm referring [`Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ioctl/hdio.txt) in kernel source(2.6.32).

Here is my main part of code:

```
fd = open("/dev/sda", O_RDONLY);  // validated fd.
retval = ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, &driveid);
if(retval < 0) {
            perror("ioctl(HDIO_GET_IDENTITY)");
            exit(3);
}
```

When I run(as root) the above code, I got below error:

```
ioctl(HDIO_GET_IDENTITY): Invalid argument
```

What is the wrong in the program?
Why I'm getting error?

**Additional Info**: OS: `CentOS-6.5`, kernel version: `2.6.32`, IA:`x86_64` (running on VMware).

Result of `hdparm -i /dev/sda` is

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a device `/dev/sda` in your system?
What type is the driveid variable?
Show us whole code, or try changing driveid to:

```
struct hd_driveid driveid;
```

Then you can print it's content, i.e.:

```
printf("Firmware Revision=%.8s\n",driveid.fw_rev);
printf("Cylinders=%d\n",driveid.cyls);
```

Also check:
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hdreg.h?v=2.6.32

Comment: driverid variable??

Comment: retval = ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, **&driveid**);
Is it struct or char or whatever?

Comment: first I tried for `char` it thrown same error and then I tried `struct hd_drive`. I got same error.

Comment: I added some extra part to my question. pls see the question again.

Comment: It's due the lack o drivers I suppose.
If you select different device ie /dev/sr0 it works perfectly.
Guess your using vmware player with centos livecd ?